# I get exception with axon-mongo 4.5, spring boot 2.4.3 and mongodb 4.2 in AxonConfig class

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, axon

***When running the project I get this exception:***

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 
'axonMongoTemplate' defined in com.springbank.user.core.configuration.AxonConfig: Bean 
instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate 
[org.axonframework.extensions.mongo.MongoTemplate]: Factory method 'axonMongoTemplate' 
threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: @Bean method 
AxonConfig.mongo called as bean reference for type [com.mongodb.MongoClient] but overridden
 by non-compatible bean instance of type [com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientImpl].
 Overriding bean of same name declared in: class path resource 
[org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/mongo/MongoAutoConfiguration.class]

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate 
[org.axonframework.extensions.mongo.MongoTemplate]: Factory method 'axonMongoTemplate' 
threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: @Bean method 
AxonConfig.mongo called as bean reference for type [com.mongodb.MongoClient] but overridden
 by non-compatible bean instance of type [com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientImpl].
 Overriding bean of same name declared in: class path resource
 [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/mongo/MongoAutoConfiguration.class]

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: @Bean method AxonConfig.mongo called as bean 
reference for type [com.mongodb.MongoClient] but overridden by non-compatible bean instance 
of type [com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientImpl]. Overriding bean of same name declared 
in: class path resource 
[org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/mongo/MongoAutoConfiguration.class]
```

***this is my axon configuration class:***

```
@Configuration
public class AxonConfig {

    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.host:127.0.0.1}")
    private String mongoHost;

    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.port:27017}")
    private int mongoPort;

    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.database:user}")
    private String mongoDatabase;

    @Bean
    public MongoClient mongo() {
        var mongoFactory = new MongoFactory();
        mongoFactory.setMongoAddresses(Collections.singletonList(new ServerAddress(mongoHost, mongoPort)));

        return mongoFactory.createMongo();
    }

    @Bean
    public MongoTemplate axonMongoTemplate() {
        return DefaultMongoTemplate.builder()
                .mongoDatabase(mongo(), mongoDatabase)
                .build();
    }
...
}
```

***The spring boot version and dependencies I use are:***

1. org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:2.4.3
2. org.axonframework:axon-spring-boot-starter:4.5.9
3. org.axonframework.extensions.mongo:axon-mongo:4.3

***this is my application.properties:***

```
#spring
server.port=8082

#mongodb
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.database=user

spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
spring.main.allow-circular-references=true
```

Comment: If you're using Axon Framework 4.5.9, I would recommend using the latest version of the Axon Mongo Extension too. This is version 4.5.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just remove the MongoClient Bean, as Spring Boot is already doing that for you.

Answer (score 0):

After several tests of dependency versions, I found the dependencies that did not conflict with each other.
Here's the list of versions used:

1. Java JDK 14
2. spring-boot-starter-parent:2.2.6.RELEASE
3. axon-spring-boot-starter:4.3.1
4. lombok:1.18.20

Using other versions of spring boot exceptions occurred.